# Gulp with TailwindCSS set-up issue - Django project

Tags: css, gulp, django-templates, tailwind-css

I have a django blog project, which is up and running on a live server.

I am using the TailwindCSS framework, and as part of that I have followed the extensive tutorial on setting up Gulp. I am experimenting with responsive design, but when I add eg:

```
<div style="flex-wrap justify-end w-full p-6 m-auto border md:bg-blue sm:bg-yellow lg:bg-black>
```

Only one (sometimes two, but not all three) of the responsive bg elements actually works when I alter the window in Chrome Dev Tools. I have tried clearing my browser cache as I know this sometimes causes problems. This got me thinking that my setup isn't right, and then I realised my understanding of gulp needs to improve.

I have the root static folder as the collection point for my gulp outputs and collectstatic, and the structure of my project is as follows:

```
nomadpad-
    -static
        -css
            -styles.css
            -custom.css
    -posts (app)
        -static
            -css
                -styles.css
                -custom.css
    -src
        -css
            -styles.css (default tailwind config file)
    - ...
```

> .gulpfile:

```
//Include Gulp

var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

//Define base folders

var src = '/src/';
var dest = '/static/';
var posts = '/posts/static/';

// Include plugins

var plugins = require("gulp-load-plugins")({
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', 'main-bower-files'],
  replaceString: /\bgulp[\-.]/
});

// Concatenate & Minify JS

gulp.task('scripts', function() {

  var jsFiles = [posts + 'js/*'];
  //plugins.mainBowerFiles() returns an array of all the main 
  //files from the packages and 
  //plugins.filter('*.js') uses gulp-filter to pass only JS files.
  gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles().concat(jsFiles))
    .pipe(plugins.filter('*.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'js'));

});

//Compile CSS

gulp.task('css', function() {

  var cssFiles = [posts +'css/*'];

  gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles().concat(cssFiles))
    .pipe(plugins.filter('*.css'))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'css'));

});

// Compile tailwind

gulp.task('tailwind', function () {
  var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
  var tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

  return gulp.src(posts + 'css/*')
    .pipe(postcss([
      tailwindcss('tailwind.js'),
      require('autoprefixer'),
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'css/*'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src('./templates/posts/*.html')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'html'))
});

// Watch for changes in files

gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch(dest + 'css/*', ['css']);
   gulp.watch(dest + 'html/*', ['html']);
   gulp.watch(dest + 'js/*', ['scripts']);

});

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: 'build',
    livereload: true,
    open: true
  });
});

// Default Task

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'tailwind', 'html', 'scripts']);

gulp.task('start', ['connect', 'watch']);
```

I appreciate the layout of this file and my structure is a little messy.

Without calling "gulp" in the command line, my Tailwind styles mostly work fine. My questions are:

1. When I call gulp, why is there no output in my static folders? What changes need to be made to ensure this works? Eg: My django templates should be being pulled through the html pipe.
2. When I call collectstatic, this updates the css files in /static (hence the two CSS files in the root static. What is the difference between using gulp and collectstatic, and how do I use them together?
3. At what point should I be using gulp and gulp start? I feel like I have put a lot of effort in to implementing this, but it is just wasted on me :-(
4. Are the issues I'm having with TailwindCSS responsive attributes related to my gulp set-up or lack of usage of gulp?

Many thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

i hope you solved this incase u did not i would recommend you use this package to easily integrate tailwind css with Django check it out here https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind